# array initializing

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

I came across this code construct in Linux and would like to understand it

```
struct mystruct {
  int x;
  int b[40];
};


/*later */

static struct mystruct e = { .x = 5,
                             .b = {-1},   
                           };
```

What does .b = {-1} do ? Does it initialize  only the first or all elements of array b ? How does it work ?

Comment: Designated Initializers: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static struct mystruct e = {
    .x = 5,
    .b = {-1},   
             };
```

here it initializes b[0] to -1. other elements are initialized to 0.

Answer (score 1):

It means **initialize the member b of the struct with an array that starts with -1 and followed by 0**

- The `.b =` is a GCC extensions. (as commented, from C99 this is part of the standard as well)
- The `{-1}` is standard array initialization.

Comment: Designated initialisers were introduced in C99 (but IIRC gcc is the only platform that implements c99)  So, calling it a *gcc extension* would be unfair.

Comment: Considering the positioning of the code (inside the braces of a `struct` initialization), I don't think it's totally correct to call the `=` part of the standard notation. Before C99, you would have written this as `e = { 5, { -1 } };`, without the equals.